# am I going to be charged for 8GB memory for cloud function even if the function used one or two times per month?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud function and I reserve 8GB RAM for it , but I call it a few times per month , is that will charge me for whole month or just for every time I hit the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Cloud Functions pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) page says:

> Fees for compute time are variable based on the amount of memory and CPU provisioned for the function. Units used in this calculation are:
>
> GB-Seconds
>
> 1 GB-second is 1 second of wallclock time with 1GB of memory provisioned
> GHz-Seconds
>
> 1 GHz-second is 1 second of wallclock time with a 1GHz CPU provisioned

So you're charged per second that the memory and CPU are active. While the Cloud Function is not active, you are not charged for that time.

If your function is only active twice per month, you will only be charged for the time period it is active those two times.